# iOS - @IBDesignable UITextField subclass shows correctly in IB, but not on device

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom `UITextField` subclass, that has an `@IBInspectable` property to round either the top or bottom corners of the text field. Everything works correctly in [Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkyeM.png), rounding the correct corners and so on, but when I run the app on a [device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ0Tp.png) (or in the simulator), it ignores my custom class and just shows the default `UITextField` implementation (I have `borderStyle` set to none in IB).

Here's my custom class:

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedCornersTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var roundBottom: Bool = false
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 22

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds, 22, 0)
    }

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds, 22, 0)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)

        let cornerRadii: CGSize = CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius)

        let topBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height / 2)
        let bottomBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: rect.height / 2, width: rect.width, height: rect.height / 2)

        let topPathRoundedCorners: UIRectCorner = roundBottom ? [] : [.TopLeft, .TopRight]
        let bottomPathRoundedCorners: UIRectCorner = roundBottom ? [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight] : []

        let topPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: topBounds, byRoundingCorners: topPathRoundedCorners, cornerRadii: cornerRadii)
        let bottomPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bottomBounds, byRoundingCorners: bottomPathRoundedCorners, cornerRadii: cornerRadii)

        topPath.appendPath(bottomPath)

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()

        layer.path = topPath.CGPath
        layer.bounds = rect
        layer.position = self.center
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        layer.lineWidth = 0
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

        self.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you created the textfield inside interface builder? If not, can you post the code where you create the UITextfield

Comment: share the code and how you are initiating that textfield

Comment: The textfield is added normally in IB, I'm not initializing it in code. I set the class to my custom class and created all the proper constraints.

Answer (score 0):

dont know if you still searching answer I had the same problem when I was trying to create custom textfield with leftview icon this piece of code did all my job. You can pretty much replace all the code in both of inits with your code

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class IconTextField: UITextField {
var imageView:UIImageView?
@IBInspectable var image: UIImage? {
    didSet { imageView?.image = image }
}
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    let rootView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:45,height:25))
    self.imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:10,y:0,width:20,height:20))
    self.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.red
    self.imageView?.image = image
    rootView.addSubview(self.imageView!)
    self.leftView = rootView
    self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    let rootView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:45,height:25))
    self.imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:10,y:0,width:20,height:20))
    self.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.red
    self.imageView?.image = image
    rootView.addSubview(self.imageView!)
    self.leftView = rootView
    self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
}



}
```